# Unable to send email through local SMTP server

Tags: c#, iis, smtp

I am working with sending email through C# in asp.net, with IIS7.
But I couldn't fix the error.

I cannot even send a message to this path

C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue

This is the simplest code I have used

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
    m.From = TextBox1.Text;
    m.To = TextBox2.Text;
    m.Subject = TextBox3.Text;
    m.Body = TextBox4.Text;
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"; //your real server goes here
    SmtpMail.Send(m);
```

note: that I manually created this path, isn't wrong? or should be created automatically?

Please HELP!

Comment: do you have smtp server on your local host

Comment: The code you are showing is not using any path at all.  SMTP is a network protocol; your code is attempting to connect to TCP port 25 on `localhost`.  (Basically, what @COLD TOLD said.)

Answer (score 0):

If you manually created the path, then the SMTP Service is not installed on your machine (assuming that you intend to use this and not a third-party SMTP server).

You can verify this by looking in the list of services (I believe it starts with Simple Mail Transport...).

Comment: Then what should I do?
SMTP virtual server is not available on Windows Feature.
I have downloaded third party SMTP 
http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html

What is the next step to do??

Comment: Try change "localhost" to the mail server of your ISP.  If you can get that to work, you can think about whether you really need or want to run your own SMTP server locally.  (I bet you don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the SmtpCredentials that's missing? And as the earlier speekers have said that the SmtpServer is it really localhost, meaning that you have a smtpserver on your machine?

I've done a SMTP mail to send som emails from my program that is working, perhaps you can find something in this that can help you?

It looks like this.

```
public class Email
{
    public Email(string recieverAdress)
    {
        mail = new MailMessage(senderAdress, recieverAdress);
    }

    private readonly MailMessage mail;
    private readonly SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com", port);
    private readonly NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    public void SendMail(string subject, string textInBody)
    {
        mail.Subject = DateTime.Now + " " + subject;
        mail.Body = textInBody;
        smtpClient.Credentials = credential;
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
}
```